# I compiled this program and the compiler keeps giving me this error

Tags: c, for-loop, warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
  int j;
  scanf ("%d",&j);
  if (j>=1&&j<=10){
    int i=0;
    int USER_NAME=100;
    char name[j][USER_NAME];
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
      scanf ("%s",name[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
      if ((i%2)==0){
        i++;
      }
      if ((i%2)!=0){
        printf ("%s\n",name[i]);
      }
    }

  }
  else (printf ("No additional constrainsts"));
  return 0;
}
```

it keeps giving me this error

```
./oddecho.c: In function 'main':
./oddecho.c:6:3: warning: ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    6 |   scanf ("%d",&j);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./oddecho.c:12:7: warning: ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   12 |       scanf ("%s",name[i]);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried using (void) before scanf in line 6 but it still keeps on bugging.
Can someone help why this error keeps on popping up?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to check the return value of `scanf` to be sure that the input was successful.

And the warnings say about that.

To avoid the warnings you can cast an expression with `scanf` to the type void

```
( void )scanf ("%d",&j);
```

Pay attention to that due to increasing the variable i two times in this for loop

```
for (i=0;i<j;i++){
  if ((i%2)==0){
    i++;
  }
  if ((i%2)!=0){
    printf ("%s\n",name[i]);
  }
}
```

It can output nothing.:)

Just write

```
for (i=0;i<j;i++){
  if ((i%2)!=0){
    printf ("%s\n",name[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using gcc 9.3.0 and `-O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` not even `(void)` silences the warning: